# Can I scale up/down automatically Azure App Service plan?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

In Azure portal, we can either scale out/in or scale up/down our App Service plan.
Additionally using Azure Monitor we can do scaling out/in automatically using some metrics or schedules.

Is it possible to do scaling up/down automatically using ex. schedule? 
I found articles about it but only for scale out/in.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible. I will outline one of the possible methods here.

You can automate scale up and scale down using Runbooks and Automation accounts.

**Step1**: Create two runbooks, one for Scale up and another for Scale down.

You can find some powershell commands for reference here [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/set-azurermappserviceplan?view=azurermps-6.13.0]

**Step2**: Create an automation account.

Details on how to create automation account can be found here [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-create-standalone-account]

**Step3**: Go to Azure Automation Accounts, and create a Schedule and link these runbooks to the schedule as per the need.

Details on how to schedule can be found here [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/schedules]

[image]

For instance, the above schedule will automatically call the “ScaleDown” runbook at 5:10 AM on 7th Feb